# Java thread not stopping even after calling cancel method?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

```
public class my {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SomeService service = new SomeService();

    CompletableFuture<Void> async = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try (AutoClosableResource<SomeService> resource = new AutoClosableResource<>(service, service::disconnect)) {
            resource.get().connect();
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("--------------inside while" + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("ouside while");
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    async.cancel(true);
    System.out.println(async.isCompletedExceptionally());
    Thread.sleep(1000);

}

public static class SomeService {
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("connect");
    }

    public Integer disconnect() {
        System.out.println("disconnect");
        return null;
    }
}

public static class AutoClosableResource<T> implements AutoCloseable {

    private final T resource;
    private final Runnable closeFunction;

    private AutoClosableResource(T resource, Runnable closeFunction) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.closeFunction = closeFunction;
    }

    public T get() {
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        closeFunction.run();
    }
}
```

}

```
-------output--------


ouside while connect
--------------inside while0
--------------inside while1
--------------inside while2
--------------inside while3
--------------inside while4 true
--------------inside while5
--------------inside while6
```

Q: Why thread is still running and printing isCompletedExceptionally() = true even I'm manually stopping it with, async.cancel(true);

Comment: Did [the documentation of `cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) say at any point that it will stop another thread?

Comment: Documentation says, If not already completed, completes this CompletableFuture with a CancellationException.

Comment: and does not say “this will stop other running threads”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
Thread is still running because CompletableFuture
cancel method has no effect to runAsync process, and doesn't interrupt the Thread.

async.isCompletedExceptionally() returns true, because cancellation throws exception CompletionException

The details:

Info from javadoc about cancel method:

> If not already completed, completes this CompletableFuture with a
>   CancellationException. Dependent CompletableFutures that have not
>   already completed will also complete exceptionally, with a
>   CompletionException caused by this CancellationException

This method just complete CompletableFuture and methods, which dependent from waiting the result getting CompletionException caused by this CancellationException. Method should be used not to interrupt thread, but to finish work on dependent methods. Future would be completed exceptionally

You should use this method in processes, where you make some work, and decided to cancel it

So, your thread continue work and terminates because of System.exit()
look into public static ForkJoinPool commonPool() javadoc

> Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically constructed;
>   its run state is unaffected by attempts to shutdown or shutdownNow.
>   However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically
>   terminated upon program System.exit. Any program that relies on
>   asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination
>   should invoke commonPool().awaitQuiescence, before exit.

Comment: thanks a ton!! , Then what would be the best practice to stop the execution of this thread?

Comment: you can stop thread by calling Thread.interrupt, or if you use executors, you can call shutdownNow method.

Comment: But usually there are no need to stop a thread externally. But if you need this, read the book Java Concurrency in Practice, chapter 7 Cancellation and Shutdown